# How to make target view match to dragged label in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I have to drag a label into a target view and i make the size of target view same as the size of label, how can i make the target view to match with label when the label is dragged into target view as i want to fit label into target view when the label is dragged..
here is code

```
- (void)endDrag:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
for(int i=0;i<_columnB.count;i++) {
    UILabel *tempLabel = (UILabel *)[_columnB objectAtIndex:i];
BOOL cancelPanGesture = YES;

   if(CGRectContainsRect(targetView.frame, tempLabel.frame)){

        gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        tempLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false;
        [tempLabel removeGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
        NSLog (@"Draged");
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to add UILabel into other View? Because you are not, you can add it as subview [targetView addSubview:<#(nonnull UIView *)#>] and setFrames of your views.

Comment: no i want to drag label into a rectangle

Comment: Well it could be over it or in it in the view hierarchy. If you want it to be over just the set frame.